# TimeZoneInfo Class and Daylight saving time

Tags: windows-phone-7, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I am trying to get the Timezone of the device (windows phone). I used this class and the property BaseUtcOffset. I live In Jordan, and it was suppose to give me +3 hours, but instead it gave me +2. i think its the daylight saving time, but i have no idea how to use it, any ideas?

```
var x = TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset;  // x.Hours = 2
```

[the correct timezone from timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`GetUtcOffset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset.aspx).

The BaseUtcOffset property returns the difference between UTC and the time zone's standard time; the GetUtcOffset method returns the difference between UTC and the time zone's time at a particular point in time.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right response. The timezone is 2 hours ahead of UTC. Local time is 3 hours ahead of UTC.

You might want to look at [`GetUtcOffset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or [`IsDaylightSavingsTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).